# Fill A6 document page border with black bars

Tags: rendering, border

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[14pt,landscape]{book}
\usepackage{fauve}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \vspace*{\fill}

  Mr. Paul \bsc{Durant}, her husband

  Miss Laura \bsc{Durant}, his daughter

  Mr. and Mrs. Jean \bsc{Racine}, his cousins

  pain you of the death of

  \paragraph*{}
  Laura \bsc{Smith}

  \vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

So, I want an to fill the border with a black line with 0,5 cm, the output could be like this:

[image: output mokup]

So, witch code have I to use to get this rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newlength\rightside
\setlength\rightside{\paperwidth}
\addtolength\rightside{-5mm}
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \rule{5mm}{\paperheight}}
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \hspace{\rightside}\rule {5mm}{\paperheight}}
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \rule[-5mm]{\paperwidth}{5mm}}
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \rule{\paperwidth}{5mm}}
}
```